# Why must I fill in this Parameter value 

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
   siteapplications.Application, Count(visits.VisitId) AS CountOfVisitId
FROM 
  visits, 
  siteapplications
WHERE 
  visits.SiteApplicationId=siteapplications.ApplicationID 
  and Month([visits.VisitTime])= month and Year([visits.VisitTime])= year
GROUP BY 
  siteapplications.Application
ORDER BY 
   CountOfVisitId DESC;
```

Maybe a stupid question but with when I run this query I need to fill in the month, year AND CountOfVisitId??

But for CountOfVisitId I need that it is calculated (hence the query)

I don't have much experience with query's but I need this one in java

Can anyone explain or solve ....

Comment: Is there a `VisitId` field in your visits table? Is your database case sensitive on field/table names? Generally, getting prompted to fill in a field value means the table/fieldname you've put into the query doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: Yes there is a field with that name and it's name is the same as VisitId ... checked this myself but thx anyway

Comment: @ Phil : Yea,  sry about that ... -> newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, depending on your brand and version of SQL, you cannot group by a column alias, or sort by a column alias. So you might try doing `ORDER BY 2 DESC` instead.

Comment: Works now without the question for a parameter ... order seems ok at first sight.  Thx  ..

Answer (score 1):

As @MJB mentioned, it is fairly common that you cannot sort by a column alias. Try this (notice the change to the `ORDER BY`):

```
SELECT 
   siteapplications.Application, Count(visits.VisitId) AS CountOfVisitId
FROM 
  visits, 
  siteapplications
WHERE 
  visits.SiteApplicationId=siteapplications.ApplicationID 
  and Month([visits.VisitTime])= month and Year([visits.VisitTime])= year
GROUP BY 
  siteapplications.Application
ORDER BY 
   Count(visits.VisitId) DESC;
```

Comment: Good to know ... I don't use query's myself all that much!  Thx